# Dynamically include variables in Scalate template

Tags: scala, scalate, scaml

I am using Scalate (scaml specifically, but the format is somewhat unimportant), and I have a number of values that are defined across a number of templates.  **These variables are not always known at compile time.**  My objective is to define them in a single shared template that I include as part of other templates (sort of a template inheritance).  I would also like these values to be lazily instantiated.  So what I want is something like this:

globals.scaml:

```
- import mylib.DataProvider._

- lazy val name = get("name")
- lazy val address = get("address)
```

template.scaml:

```
= include("globals.scaml")
The address for #{name} is #{address}
```

I have messed around with various schemes, including reversing this such that globals.scaml loads the correct template while passing in some variables, like this:

globals.scaml:

```
-@ val template: String
- import mylib.DataProvider._

- val data = Map("name" -> get("name"), "address" -> get("address))
- render(template, data)
```

But this only works if I actually declare the vals in the template as well, like this:

```
-@ val name:String
-@ val address:String

The address for #{name} is #{address}
```

Problem is this is actually worse than just repeating myself in every template, because I still have to declare all the vals and I don't get lazy evaluation.

Is there a way (without writing my own pre-parser) to do this in Scalate?